# Unable to build image with Gradle Docker Plugin's Palantir

Tags: docker, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I am unable to build a docker image using with Gradle Docker Plugin's Palantir using the `./gradlew docker` command.

It give the following error below.

```
> Task :docker FAILED
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat src/main/java/MyMainClass.java: file does not exist

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task '*docker'.
> Process 'command 'docker'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stracktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 548ms
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

I tried `docker build -t <MY_GIVEN_IMAGE_NAME> .` in the same directory and it works fine.

Below is my **Dockerfile** and my **build.gradle** file

My **Dockerfile** code

```
FROM openjdk:22
WORKDIR /src
COPY /src/main/java/MyMainClass.java /src
RUN javac MyMainClass.java
CMD ["java", "MyMainClass"]
```

My **build.gradle** code

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.35.0'
id 'com.palantir.docker-run' version '0.35.0'
}

group 'docker.dockering.dockeringdocker'
version '1.0.1'


docker {
    name 'my_open_jdk_image_palatir_build_image'
    files '/src/main/java/MyMainClass.java'
    dockerfile file('Dockerfile')
}
dockerRun {
    name 'my_open_jdk_image_palatir_build_container'
    image 'my_open_jdk_image_palatir_build_image'
}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'MyMainClass'
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the error message in plain text?  Have you tried to debug the Gradle-driven image build at all to see what might be in the build context?

Comment: @DavidMaze Alright done editing.

Comment: @DavidMaze Hi, I am also relatively new to Gradle, how do I debug the Gradle-driven image build to see the build context?

Comment: One debug thing I might try is to copy in the entire build context `COPY ./ ./` and then set `CMD ls` to try to figure out where in the filesystem it's starting.